# Hide Bundle price from onepage checkout?

Tags: magento-1.9, price, onepage-checkout, bundled-product

Does anyone know where the code located that calls the bundle price next to the product title in the checkout?  I have a digital download bundle that is free but I don't want the $0.00 displayed next to it. I've looked through the item.phtml file and found nothing so far.  Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Helper/Catalog/Product/Configuration.php
in class Mage_Bundle_Helper_Catalog_Product_Configuration::getBundleOptions 
line 129